# Аналоги библиотек для работы с картинками

Tags: c#, изображения, библиотеки

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли аналоги библиотеки *pillow* из *python* на *C#*? Если есть, то можете накинуть ссылок на документацию?

Comment: Советую не аналог искать, а конкретный функционал, ибо библиотек по работе с изображением на C# уйма, зависит все от требования к ним.

Comment: `System.Drawing` если наугад.